# TestNg + Maven + Allure: How to generate correct name for suites in the report

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, allure

I have an issue with Allure report in our auto tests.

Previously we used JUnit (+ maven + allure), but now I need re-configure tests to start browser only once per run and only for specific groups of tests. I tried to solve this in JUnit, but didn't manage :( So now I am trying TestNg - it resolves such tasks easier, using beforeGroups annotations.

But I faced with a trouble: allure report now places all tests (from all packages and classes) to a single suite.

[image: [Example]]

In this screenshot, result of running two classes. 
I've read that this is a trouble of TestNG adaptor for Allure, but I don't know how to fix that.

We have **a lot** of test classes with tests, so creating bunch of xml files with one class in each and updating them doesn't look good neither. Is there some possibility to override default suites generation for allure? Or customize allure adaptor?

What I prefer to have in report: list of classes names with test methods list in each, as it was in JUnit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out a brand new Allure TestNG adaptor:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
   <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
   <version>2.0-BETA5</version>
</dependency>
```

The docs available [here](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/2.0/#_testng). It provides the results in a new format, so you also need to use Allure 2 (grab it from [bintray](https://bintray.com/qameta/generic/allure2/2.0-BETA8)) to generate the report.

Comment: Thanks, I will try.

Comment: I've just got the time to check. Looks much more better, thanks a lot. 
One additional question, previously we used allure-maven-plugin for report generation. Is there a possibility to do exactly same instead of using bintray version?

Comment: yep, you can use a new allure-maven plugin available here https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-maven . The version 2.6 supports Allure 2, but the docs outdated, will update soon

Comment: The new plugin' coordinates is io.qameta.allure:allure-maven:2.6

Comment: Hm, I assume it was not published to maven repo yet, is it?

Comment: ops, the right version is 2.7, and yep, it is not synced to jcenter/maven central yet (waiting for approve, usually takes few days). At the moment you can grab it from our bintray https://bintray.com/qameta/maven/allure-maven

Comment: I will wait for it appearing in maven central. Thanks a lot!